# Python pandas, how to convert specific excel date to json

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have a excel file and want to convert excel to json file.

this is my excel

```
            1 Year Period         2 Year Period      
 Max      10%                     11%
 Period   Jul 1996 to 1997        Jul 1997 to 1998
 Min      -30%                    -40%
 Period   mar 2002 to Mar 2003     mar 2003 to mar 2004
```

This is Json format i want

```
                    "from": {
                        "month": 6,
                        "year": 1996
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "month": 6,
                        "year": 1997
                    }
```

question is how convert "Period" row such as Jul 1996 to 1997 to json format like

```
from": { "month": 6, "year": 1996 }, "to": { "month": 6, "year": 1997 }
```

Comment: So question is how convert first `Period` row and column `1 Year Period` to string `Jul 1996 to 1997` and then to `from": {
                        "month": 6,
                        "year": 1996
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "month": 6,
                        "year": 1997
                    }` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.